# How do I get the users that belong to a group in Active Directory?

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I have a dropdownlist that I am trying to fill with users that belong to a certain group in Active Directory.

The group name is OverRiders and 8 people are members of this group. More members could be added.

I have the following dropdown but I run the code, the dropdown is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Please see code:

```
        Private Sub FillDropdown()
    Dim oroot As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=OverRiders,OU=Departments,DC=domain,DC=com")
Dim osearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(oroot)
Dim oresult As SearchResultCollection
Dim result As SearchResult
Dim list As New List(Of String)

    osearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=group)(cn={0}))"
    ' search filter; only display emp with firstname / lastname pair
    osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name") ' member
    oresult = osearcher.FindAll()


    For Each result In oresult
        If Not result.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("name").Value Is Nothing Then
            list.Add(result.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("name").Value.ToString())
            Call list.Sort()
        End If
Next
emplist.DataSource = list
emplist.DataBind()

End Sub
```

I have been able to confirm that the group does exist and the group name is valid.
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You need to start by checking if your oresult object is empty or not. If it is then your LDAP search filter isn't working properly. If it isn't then the attribute you are looking for isn't there. Find this out and let us know.

Comment: I have done those checks already.

There is something wrong with this:

'osearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=group)(cn={0}))"'

I am not sure what the objectcategory should be or if there should be objectClass. Hopefully, more experienced experts can help me out.

I honestly didn't it would be hard to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I can only speak from experience; the LDAP query I use for an intranet telephone directory app is (&(objectClass=person)(telephoneNumber=*) and then I add one or more filters depending on what the user is searching for (i.e. (SN="surname"*)). I would try just the objectCategory / objectClass query first and see if you get a response from your AD before attempting to narrow things down further.

Comment: I have another dropdownlist that works perfectly.

Only difference between this dropdownlist I posted above and the one that works perfectly is that this one I posted is looking for users of a SPECIFIC group while the one that works just queries all users from Active Directory. So, there is something I am sure that needs to be tweaked with the objectcategory and class, I guess.

Comment: Sounds like it. Maybe you could just use the query that works and write your own filter outside of System.DirectoryServices to find what you need? Not optimal, but a solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed:

```
Dim oroot As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=OverRiders,OU=Departments,DC=domain,DC=com")
```

to

```
Dim oroot As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=domain,DC=com")
```

and this:

```
osearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=group)(cn={0}))"
```

to this:

```
osearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=overRiders,OU=Departments,DC=domain,DC=com)‌​)"
```

Everything else remain unchanged.

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this is what worked for me in a similar situation:

```
    Dim UsersInGroup As New Collection()

    Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://[Domain]")

    Dim MemberSearcher As New DirectorySearcher

    With MemberSearcher
        .SearchRoot = de
        .Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=Group)(CN=" & Group & "))"
        .PropertiesToLoad.Add("Member")
    End With

    Dim mySearchResults As SearchResult = MemberSearcher.FindOne()

    For Each User In mySearchResults.Properties("Member")
        UsersInGroup.Add(User)
    Next
```

Comment: hi Michael, what do I put the name of my AD directory here?

Comment: I normally use rootdse. this will make it work on what ever domain you are logged in under.